# HTTP traffic forwarding

Tags: proxy, http, forwarding

What is the best way to forward all the HTTP traffic going through a wireless access point to an NT machine connected to the same hub? The traffic will not be external traffic (no NAT) it will be all local traffic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use linux-based firmware for your accesspoint [eg [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)] you can turn it into a router and there you can do traffic redirecting based on source/destination ip as described [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy).